# Wordpress custom widget undefined variable notice

Tags: widgets, variables, debug

I am developing a theme and I have created a custom widget for it.

When I turn on debug mode I get the following notices,

```
NOTICE: wp-content/themes/integral/inc/widgets/feature_widget.php:92 - Undefined variable: title 
wp_list_widgets, call_user_func_array, wp_widget_control, call_user_func_array, WP_Widget->form_callback, Integral_Feature_Widget->form

NOTICE: wp-content/themes/integral/inc/widgets/feature_widget.php:97 - Undefined variable: text
wp_list_widgets, call_user_func_array, wp_widget_control, call_user_func_array, WP_Widget->form_callback, Integral_Feature_Widget->form

NOTICE: wp-content/themes/integral/inc/widgets/feature_widget.php:110 - Undefined variable: textarea
wp_list_widgets, call_user_func_array, wp_widget_control, call_user_func_array, WP_Widget->form_callback, Integral_Feature_Widget->form
```

This is the contents of the widget file,

```
<?php 
/**
 * new WordPress Widget format
 * Wordpress 2.8 and above
 * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets
 */
class Integral_Feature_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @return void
     **/
    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'wcp_image', 'description' => 'Add a feature to the homepage features section.' );
        parent::__construct( 'Integral_feature', 'Integral - Feature Widget', $widget_ops );
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the HTML for this widget.
     *
     * @param array  An array of standard parameters for widgets in this theme
     * @param array  An array of settings for this widget instance
     * @return void Echoes it's output
     **/
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

       // these are the widget options
       $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
       $text = $instance['text'];
       $image_url = $instance['image_url'];
       $textarea = apply_filters( 'widget_textarea', empty( $instance['textarea'] ) ? '' : $instance['textarea'], $instance );
       echo $before_widget;
       // Display the widget
       echo '';

       // Check if text is set
       if( $text ) {
          echo '<i class="fa '.$text.' pull-left featureicon"></i>';
       }
       if( !$text && $image_url) {
          echo '<img  src="'.$image_url.'" class="fimage">';
       }

       // Check if title is set
       if ( $title ) {
          echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
       }

       // Check if textarea is set
       if( $textarea ) { echo wpautop($textarea); }
       echo '';
       echo $after_widget;
    }

    /**
     * Deals with the settings when they are saved by the admin. Here is
     * where any validation should be dealt with.
     *
     * @param array  An array of new settings as submitted by the admin
     * @param array  An array of the previous settings
     * @return array The validated and (if necessary) amended settings
     **/
    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

        // update logic goes here
        $instance = $old_instance;
          // Fields
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['text'] = strip_tags($new_instance['text']);
        $instance['image_url'] = strip_tags($new_instance['image_url']);
        if ( current_user_can('unfiltered_html') )
            $instance['textarea'] =  $new_instance['textarea'];
        else $instance['textarea'] = stripslashes( wp_filter_post_kses( addslashes($new_instance['textarea']) ) );

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Displays the form for this widget on the Widgets page of the WP Admin area.
     *
     * @param array  An array of the current settings for this widget
     * @return void Echoes it's output
     **/
    function form( $instance ) {
        extract($instance);

?>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Feature Title', 'integral'); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>"><?php _e('Feature Icon Class', 'integral'); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" />
    <small>Copy and paste the required icon class from the <a href="https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/" target="_blank">Fontawesome Icons List</a> and choose from 600+ icons.</small>
    </p>
    <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image_url'); ?>"><?php _e('Feature Image', 'integral'); ?></label>
    <br /><small>Or instead of using an icon you can upload an image.</small>
    <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image_url'); ?>" type="text" class="image-url" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('image_url'); ?>" value="<?php if (isset($image_url)) echo esc_attr($image_url); ?>" style="width: 100%;" />
    <input data-title="Image in Widget" data-btntext="Select it" class="button upload_image_button" type="button" value="<?php _e('Upload','integral') ?>" /> <input data-title="Image in Widget" data-btntext="Select it" class="button clear_image_button" type="button" value="<?php _e('Clear','integral') ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="img-prev">
        <?php if (isset($image_url) && $image_url) { echo '<img src="'.$image_url.'" style="max-width: 100%;">';} ?>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('textarea'); ?>"><?php _e('Feature Description', 'integral'); ?></label>
    <textarea class="widefat" rows="5" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('textarea'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('textarea'); ?>"><?php echo $textarea; ?></textarea>
    <small>No limit on the amount of text and HTML is allowed.</small>
    </p>
<?php
    }
}
// End of Widget Class
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', "register_widget( 'Integral_Feature_Widget' );" ) );
?>
```

I think I have to set a default variable for those fields, but I am not sure how to do it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can you [`wp_parse_args`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_args) to merge `$instance` with a default array. So, you would start you `form` function not with `extract($instance)` but with

```
$defaults = array( 
    'title'         => 'Your title',
    'text'          => '...',
    'image_url'     => '...'
    'textarea'      => '...'
    );
$instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, $defaults);
```